# Unable to install electron app on Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, electron

I built an express/ejs application and turned it into an electron app. I can launch the app just fine using node commandline. However, I recently packaged the app using electron-packager and built it using electron-installer-windows. When I install the executable file I get the following error:

[image: Error]

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You are trying to require a non-existent file `index.js`. I'm pretty sure this is a problem with how you package your app.

Comment: I am not sure where it is getting this from. I have an index.ejs file. But not an index.js.

Answer (score 0):

Your main.js file may not be configured properly. You can use sample electron application official template on github.

[Electron sample application](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start)

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try.